# echo php form validation with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-form-validator

Good day to everyone,

I am trying to create a CMS with php and I am having a trouble to do the next:

I want to delete, edit or add information to my page, so to do it I am using several buttoms and AJAX to load the form to a display div. I get the button delete to work perfectly,  but when I try the add and edit button it doesn´t  work due to that they ask to append some html text that also contains php code so there is no PHP interpreter to read it.

**My approach:**

1. `<div class="displayHere col-xs-12"> </div>` is empty.
2. I click Add button, It goes to ajax.php and append the form and form validation.
3. I filled the form and click add_document, the form validation (php) check the datas and upload the document if it is possible and set some outputs variables.

How can I get this functionality? Probably I am approaching badly the problem, I hope some of you can share your experience with me.

For example, for the add function, I want to get this functionality:

```
<div id="bodyDiv">
  <!--HEADER-->
  <header id="header" class=" row">
    <?php 
          include 'includes/loadHeader.php';
          echo '<nav class="col-xs-6 cms_nav">
            <ul>
              <li><input id="buttonAdd" type="submit" class="button buttonFuncitonality" name="AÑADIR" value="AÑADIR" /></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>';
    ?>
     <div class="displayHere col-xs-12">
    <?php


          function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
          }


          $nameErr =  $dateErr = $typeErr = $fileErr = "";
          $name = $date = $type = $file = $matches =  "";
          $success = true;

           if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

              // name, date, type, path
                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                  $nameErr = "El nombre es necesario";
                  $success = FALSE;
                } 
                else {
                  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                }

                if (!empty($_POST["date"])) {
                  $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
                  $time_pattern = "(([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))?";
                  //Check the date format  http://www.phpliveregex.com/  (0|[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])
                  if (preg_match("/^(0|[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-9]{4})\s*".$time_pattern."/",$date,$matches)){
                    echo "<script>console.log('yeahh format 1');</script>";
                    echo "<script>console.log('yeahh format 1  ". $date. "  ".  str_replace("-","/",$matches['0']) ."   yeahh format 1');</script>";
                    $date = str_replace("-","/",$matches['0']);
                  }
                  elseif (preg_match("/^(0|[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-9]{4})\s*".$time_pattern."/",$date, $matches)){

                  }
                  else{
                    echo "<script>console.log('noooo  ". $date. "  " . $matches['0'] ."   yeahh format 1');</script>";
                    $dateErr = "Formato de fecha incorrecto";
                    $success = FALSE;
                  }

                  //The formar mysql is expecting DATETIME '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                  if(empty($dateErr)){

                     if( preg_match("/\s([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/",$date)){
                        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y H:i', $date);
                        $date = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i');
                     }
                     else{
                        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y', $date);
                        $date = $date->format('d-m-Y');
                     }

                     echo "<script>console.log('date ".$date."');</script>";

                  }
                }

                if (empty($_POST["type"]) ) {
                  $typeErr = "El tipo de documento es necesario";
                  $success = FALSE;

                } 
                else{
                  $type = test_input($_POST["type"]);
                }

                // Upload the file
                if($success ){

                  if(empty($_FILES['documentPDF']['name'])){
                    $fileErr = "Debes añadir un documento pdf ";

                  }
                  else{
                    $target_dir = "shareholders_documents/".$type. "/";
                    $file_name =  basename($_FILES["documentPDF"]["name"]);
                    $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;

                    echo "<script>console.log('".$target_file."');</script>";
                    $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                    //echo " vamos a ver que hay aqui " .$target_file;
                    // Check if pdf already exist
                    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                        $fileErr = "Este documento ya existe.";
                        $success = false;
                    }
                    if ($_FILES["documentPDF"]["size"] > 500000) {
                        $fileErr = "El documento es demasiado largo";
                        $success = false;
                    }
                    // Allow certain file formats
                    if($fileType != "pdf"  ) {
                        $fileErr = "El documento debe estar en formato pdf";
                        $success = false;
                    }

                    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                    if ($success == true ) {
                        //echo "\nmove_uploaded_file(".$_FILES["documentPDF"]["tmp_name"].", ".$target_file.")" ;
                        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["documentPDF"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                            $fileErr ="No se ha podido almacenar el documento ". basename( $_FILES["documentPDF"]["name"]);
                            $success = false;
                        }
                    } 
                  }

                }

              }


              $result=""; 
              // Now we have to prepare the data for the sql operation

              if( isset( $_POST["insert"] ) && $success ){
                $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
                $date = $date;
                $type =  test_input($_POST['type']);
                $path =  $file_name;
                $id = $type ." ". $date . " " . $path ; 

                //Create $sql sentence
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `shareholders_documents`(`id`, `name`, `date`, `type`, `path`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."',STR_TO_DATE('".$date."', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'),'".$type."','".$path."')";
                $sqlResult = $conn->query($sql);
                $message= "";
                if($conn->error){
                  $message = $conn->error;
                  $success = false;
                }

                //Sending email
                if ($success){
                  $result='<div class="alert alert-success margin-top-big">El documento se ha subido correctamente'.$name." ".$date." ".$type." ". $path. "\n" . $sql. '</div>';

                }
                else{
                 $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top-big">Algo ha fallado y el documento no se ha podido subir ' . $message . '</div>';
                 if(empty($fileErr)){ //If we cannot insert the document we must delete the file
                      unlink($target_file);
                 }
                }




             }

             //Cleaning global array $_POST  
              $_POST = array();
              $_FILE = array();




          ?>

          <div id="insertForm" class="col-xs-12 shareholdersForm">
             <h3>Insertar</h3> 
              <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                 <input class="col-xs-12 form-control  <?php  if( !empty($nameErr) ) {echo 'boxError alert-danger ' ;} ?> " value="<?php if( !$success ) {echo $name;}?>" type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php if( !empty($nameErr) ) {echo $nameErr;}else{ echo 'nombre';}?>">   
                 <input class="col-xs-12 form-control  <?php  if( !empty($dateErr) ) {echo 'boxError alert-danger ' ;} ?> "  value="<?php if( !$success ) {echo $date;}?>" type="text" name="date" placeholder="<?php if( !empty($dateErr) ) {echo $dateErr;}else{ echo 'fecha (Ejemplo de formato: 31/10/2017 17:54)';}?>">  
                 <select class="col-xs-12 form-control  <?php  if( !empty($typeErr) ) {echo 'boxError alert-danger ' ;} ?> " name="type">    
                   <option value="hechosRelevantes">hecho relevantes</option>    
                   <option value="informacionEmpresa">informacion empresa</option> 
                   <option value="informacionFinanciera">informacion financiera</option>   
                  </select>   
                <input class="col-xs-12" type="file" name="documentPDF" accept="application/pdf" >
                <span class="error col-xs-12" style="float:left"> <?php if( !empty($fileErr) ) {echo "* ". $fileErr;} ?> </span>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="insert">Añadir</button>
                <?php if ( !empty($result) ){  echo $result; } ?>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In my website I have a add button which should upload the form validation using AJAX.

```
<?php


//echo "piece of shit";
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'AÑADIR':  //ADD FUNCTIONALITY
            add_document();
            break;

        default:
          echo "La accion no se indentifica\n" ;
          break;
    }
}

function add_document() {
  echo ' <div id="insertForm" class="col-xs-12 shareholdersForm">
             <h3>Insertar</h3> 
              <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                 <input class="col-xs-12 form-control  <?php  if( !empty($nameErr) ) {echo "boxError alert-danger " ;} ?> " value="<?php if( !$success ) {echo $name;}?>" type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php if( !empty($nameErr) ) {echo $nameErr;}else{ echo "nombre";}?>">   
                 <input class="col-xs-12 form-control  <?php  if( !empty($dateErr) ) {echo "boxError alert-danger " ;} ?> "  value="<?php if( !$success ) {echo $date;}?>" type="text" name="date" placeholder="<?php if( !empty($dateErr) ) {echo $dateErr;}else{ echo "fecha (Ejemplo de formato: 31/10/2017 17:54)";}?>">  
                 <select class="col-xs-12 form-control  <?php  if( !empty($typeErr) ) {echo "boxError alert-danger" ;} ?> " name="type">    
                   <option value="hechosRelevantes">hecho relevantes</option>    
                   <option value="informacionEmpresa">informacion empresa</option> 
                   <option value="informacionFinanciera">informacion financiera</option>   
                  </select>   
                <input class="col-xs-12" type="file" name="documentPDF" accept="application/pdf" >
                <span class="error col-xs-12" style="float:left"> <?php if( !empty($fileErr) ) {echo "* ". $fileErr;} ?> </span>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="insert">Añadir</button>
                <?php if ( !empty($result) ){  echo $result; } ?>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>';

}

function load_delete_document_form($id) {
    echo ' <div id="deleteForm" class="col-xs-12 shareholdersForm"> 
      <h3>Eliminar '. $id.'</h3>  
      <form id="'.$id.'"  method="POST"> 
        <button  class="btn btn-default buttonFunctionality" type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">Eliminar</button> 
      </form>

    </div>


                ';
    exit;
}


?>
```

To use that AJAX code I use this jquery function in my website:

```
                      <script>
                  //$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("body").on("click",".buttonFunctionality", function(){

                        if($('.displayHere').length !== 0){
                          $('.displayHere').children().remove()
                        }
                          var action = $(this).val();
                          var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                          console.log(action + "   " + id);
                          $.post("includes/ajax.php",{ action: action, id: id}, function(data, status){
                              console.log("click1 " + id );
                              console.log("data " + data);
                              $('.displayHere').append(data); // This append will append the code I will need in my page

                          });

                    });
                //});
                </script>
```

As a result of my code I get the form with a buch of php code without   interpretation.

Comment: "it doesn´t work due to that...." any errors?

Comment: Your mixing of HTML and PHP makes little sense. That php inline code will not run since you are not requesting it right. You should be building the string on the server and returning it, not putting the inline code in it directly.

Comment: When I run it as in the first example, I mean, I write the php form validation direcly it adds the information perfectly, but i do not know how to do it using AJAX, how would you do it, I do not know how to build the string on the server because I do not have the information I want to validate yet,  epascarello ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check it with html attribute `required` for empty input
and for other like user just entered **spaces in comment input** using php function `empty($value)`

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is from your add_document() function;

since it's php you don't have to use `<?php` `?>` but instead concatenate the strings together and then echo the whole thing

Should looks like this :

```
function add_document() {
    $div = ' <div id="insertForm" class="col-xs-12 shareholdersForm">
         <h3>Insertar</h3> 
          <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
             <input class="col-xs-12 form-control  ';
    if( !empty($nameErr) ) {
        $div .= "boxError alert-danger ";
    }
    $div .= '" value="';
    if( !$success ) {
        $div .= $name;
    }
    $div .= '" type="text" name="name" placeholder="';

    //more code

    echo $div;

}
```

Hope you get the idea

---

**Edit :**

The other issue here is the fact that you are trying to do form verif on the ajax side of the form without re-submiting it;

I would suggest using default form validation by adding `required` to your input tags;

Your function should look like that :

```
function add_document() {
    $nameVal = (!$success ) ? $name : "";
    $dateVal = (!$success ) ? $date : "";
    $resultVal = (!empty($result) ) ? $result : "";

    $nameErrVal = (!empty($nameErr)) ? $nameErr : "nombre";
    $dateErrVal = (!empty($dateErr)) ? "boxError alert-danger " : "";
    $dateErrVal2 = (!empty($dateErr)) ? $dateErr : "fecha (Ejemplo de formato: 31/10/2017 17:54)";
    $typeErrVal = (!empty($typeErr)) ? "boxError alert-danger" : "";
    $fileErrVal = (!empty($fileErr)) ? "* ". $fileErr : "";

    $div = ' <div id="insertForm" class="col-xs-12 shareholdersForm">
         <h3>Insertar</h3> 
          <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
             <input class="col-xs-12 form-control " value="'.$nameVal.'" type="text" name="name" placeholder="'
             .$nameErrVal.'" required>   
             <input class="col-xs-12 form-control  '.$dateErrVal.'"  value="'.$dateVal.'" 
             type="text" name="date" placeholder="'.$dateErrVal2.'" required>  
             <select class="col-xs-12 form-control  '.$typeErrVal.'" name="type">    
               <option value="hechosRelevantes">hecho relevantes</option>    
               <option value="informacionEmpresa">informacion empresa</option> 
               <option value="informacionFinanciera">informacion financiera</option>   
              </select>   
            <input class="col-xs-12" type="file" name="documentPDF" accept="application/pdf" required>
            <span class="error col-xs-12" style="float:left"> '.$fileErrVal.' </span>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="insert">Añadir</button>
            '.$resultVal.'
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>';

    echo $div;

}
```

It should output something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/p6147nh0/11/

Comment: Yes, you are right, If I code it as you are telling my it will add the add_document_form well, but in the moment the form is submited it won´t check nameErr, success and the other variable anymore.

Comment: This is my actual approach:  1- <div class="displayHere col-xs-12"> </div> is empty.
2- I click Add button, It goes to ajax.php and append the form and form validation.
3- I filled the form and click add_document, the form validation (php) check the datas and upload the document if it is possible and set some outputs variables.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to this. It was my first approach:

1. `<div class="displayHere col-xs-12"> </div>` is empty.
2. I click Add button, It goes to ajax.php and append the form and form
       validation. (This part is wrong or at least I did not get it to
       work, I cannot append the form valitation to the front. Instead, I
       have to check everything to the AJAX file which will check
       everything and will return just the html already formed.)

   3- I filled the form and click add_document, the form validation (php)
   check the datas and upload the document if it is possible and set
   some outputs variables.

As it did not work, I tried to send to my AJAX all the information needed to validate the form and get from it just the html already created.

1. is empty.
2. I click the button ADD (there are two add buttons, one to upload the form and other to send the form filled), it will go to AJAX and will return to me the
   form that will be appened to the page.

   hecho relevantes    
        informacion empresa 
        informacion financiera   
          
     
      
     Añadir
3. The form will be filled and the Añadir click. The button has associated a
   javascript function.

   ```
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                   $("body").on("click",".buttonFunctionality", function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();


                         var action = $(this).val();
                         var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                         var formdata = new FormData($("#insertForm>form")[0]);
                         formdata.append("action", action);
                         formdata.append("id",id);
                         $.ajax({
                           url: "includes/ajax.php", // Url to which the request is send
                           type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                           data: formdata, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                           contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                           cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                           processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                           success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                           {
                             console.log("SUCCESS");
                             if($('.displayHere').length !== 0){
                               $('.displayHere').children().remove()
                             }
                             $(".displayHere").append(data);


                           }
                         });

                   });



                   });

               //});
               </script>
   ```

3-At the begining I tried to create a JSON to send the information to my ajax.php, but then, I realised there is a method var formdata = new FormData($("#insertForm>form") that gave the all the information I need to deal with the  form valitation ($_POST, $_File ... ). So finally this method was the last detail I needed to solve it.

This function send to ajax.php the information, and in ajax.php deals with the php code.

AJAX.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.inc.php';
$message = $sql = "";



if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'AÑADIR':
            add_document($_POST['action']);
            break;
        case 'add':
             echo("<script>console.log('  ADD ');</script>");
             echo("<script>console.log('                        PHP tmp_name :". $_FILES['documentPDF']['tmp_name']."');</script>");
            if(isset($_FILES["documentPDF"]["type"]))
            {
              echo("<script>console.log('                        PHP tmp_name :". $_FILES['documentPDF']['tmp_name']."');</script>");
            }

            add_document($_POST['action']);
            break;
        case 'Editar':
          if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            load_edit_document($_POST['id']);
            break;
          }
        case 'Edit':
          if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            edit_document($_POST['id']);
            break;
          }
        case 'Eliminar':
          if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            echo("<script>console.log('PHP id: ".$_POST['id']."');</script>");
            load_delete_document_form($_POST['id']);
            break;
          }
        case 'Delete':
          if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            delete_document($_POST['id']);
            break;
          }
        default:
          echo "La accion no se indentifica\n" ;
          break;
    }
}

function add_document($action) {
  echo "<script>console.log('INSIDE ADD_DOCUMENT');</script>";





  function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
  }


  $nameErr =  $dateErr = $typeErr = $fileErr = "";
  $name = $date = $type = $file = $matches =  "";
  $success = true;

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" &&  $action == 'add' ){
    echo "<script>console.log('INSIDE REQUEST_METHOD');</script>";
    // name, date, type, path
      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "El nombre es necesario";
        $success = FALSE;
      } 
      else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
      }

      if (!empty($_POST["date"])) {
        $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
        $time_pattern = "(([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))?";
        //Check the date format  http://www.phpliveregex.com/  (0|[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])
        if (preg_match("/^(0|[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-9]{4})\s*".$time_pattern."/",$date,$matches)){
          echo "<script>console.log('yeahh format 1');</script>";
          echo "<script>console.log('yeahh format 1  ". $date. "  ".  str_replace("-","/",$matches['0']) ."   yeahh format 1');</script>";
          $date = str_replace("-","/",$matches['0']);
        }
        elseif (preg_match("/^(0|[1-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-9]{4})\s*".$time_pattern."/",$date, $matches)){

        }
        else{
          echo "<script>console.log('noooo  ". $date. "  " . $matches['0'] ."   yeahh format 1');</script>";
          $dateErr = "Formato de fecha incorrecto";
          $success = FALSE;
        }

        //The formar mysql is expecting DATETIME '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        if(empty($dateErr)){

           if( preg_match("/\s([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/",$date)){
              $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y H:i', $date);
              $date = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i');
           }
           else{
              $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y', $date);
              $date = $date->format('d-m-Y');
           }

           echo "<script>console.log('date ".$date."');</script>";

        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["type"]) ) {
        $typeErr = "El tipo de documento es necesario";
        $success = FALSE;

      } 
      else{
        $type = test_input($_POST["type"]);
      }

      // Upload the file
      if($success ){

        if(empty($_FILES['documentPDF']['name'])){
          $fileErr = "Debes añadir un documento pdf ";

        }
        else{
          $target_dir = "../shareholders_documents/".$type. "/";
          $file_name =  basename($_FILES["documentPDF"]["name"]);
          $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;

          echo "<script>console.log('".$target_file."');</script>";
          $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
          //echo " vamos a ver que hay aqui " .$target_file;
          // Check if pdf already exist
          if (file_exists($target_file)) {
              $fileErr = "Este documento ya existe.";
              $success = false;
          }
          if ($_FILES["documentPDF"]["size"] > 1000000) {
              $fileErr = "El documento es demasiado largo";
              $success = false;
          }
          // Allow certain file formats
          if($fileType != "pdf"  ) {
              $fileErr = "El documento debe estar en formato pdf";
              $success = false;
          }

          // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
          if ($success == true ) {

              if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["documentPDF"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                  $fileErr ="No se ha podido almacenar el documento ". basename( $_FILES["documentPDF"]["name"]);
                  $success = false;
              }
          } 
        }

      }

    }


    $result=""; 
    // Now we have to prepare the data for the sql operation

    if(  $action == 'add' && $success ){

      $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
      $date = $date;
      $type =  test_input($_POST['type']);
      $path =  $file_name;
      $id = $type ." ". $date . " " . $path ; 

      //Create $sql sentence
       include 'dbh.inc.php';
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `shareholders_documents`(`id`, `name`, `date`, `type`, `path`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."',STR_TO_DATE('".$date."', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'),'".$type."','".$path."')";
      $sqlResult = $conn->query($sql);
      $message= "";
      if($conn->error){
        $message = $conn->error;
        $success = false;
      }

      //Sending email
      if ($success){
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success margin-top-big">El documento se ha subido correctamente'.$name." ".$date." ".$type." ". $path. "\n" . $sql. '</div>';

      }
      else{
       $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top-big">Algo ha fallado y el documento no se ha podido subir ' . $message . '</div>';
       if(empty($fileErr)){ //If we cannot insert the document we must delete the file
            unlink($target_file);
       }
      }




   }

   //Cleaning global array $_POST  
    $_POST = array();
    $_FILE = array();


  //
  // Form validation
  //


  $div = ' <div id="insertForm" class="col-xs-12 shareholdersForm">
             <h3>Insertar</h3> 
              <form  method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                 <input class="col-xs-12 form-control addingForm ' ;
  if( !empty($nameErr) ) {
    $div .= "boxError alert-danger " ;
  }
  $div.= '" value="';
  if( !$success ) {
    $div .= $name;
  } 
  $div .='" type="text" name="name" placeholder=" ';
  if( !empty($nameErr) ) {
    $div .= $nameErr;
  }else{ 
    $div .= "nombre";
  }
  $div .= '" required>   
          <input class="col-xs-12 form-control addingForm ';
  if( !empty($dateErr) ) {
    $div .= "boxError alert-danger " ;
  } 
  $div .=' "  value="';
  if( !$success ) {
    $div .= $date;
  } 
  $div .= '" type="text" name="date" placeholder=" ';
  if( !empty($dateErr) ) {
    $div.= $dateErr;
  }else{ 
    $div.= "fecha (Ejemplo de formato: 31/10/2017 17:54)";
  } 
  $div .='" required>  
          <select class="col-xs-12 form-control addingForm ';
  if( !empty($typeErr) ) {
    $div .= "boxError alert-danger" ;
  } 
  $div.= ' " name="type">    
                   <option value="hechosRelevantes">hecho relevantes</option>    
                   <option value="informacionEmpresa">informacion empresa</option> 
                   <option value="informacionFinanciera">informacion financiera</option>   
                  </select>   
                <input class="col-xs-12 addingForm" type="file" id="documentPDF" name="documentPDF" accept="application/pdf" >
                <span class="error col-xs-12" style="float:left">';
  if( !empty($fileErr) ) {
    $div .= "* ";
    $div .=  $fileErr;
  } 
  $div .= ' </span>
                <button class="btn btn-default buttonFunctionality" type="submit" name="add"  value="add">Añadir</button>
                ';
 if ( !empty($result) ){  
    $div.= $result; 
  } 
  $div .='
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>';


  echo $div ;


}
```

So this is the way I got to solve it, I know it now very complicated for I am sure a lot of beginers get stack in it as I got. I hope I will save some time to anyone.

Thanks to the people who has try to help me.